# RHEL8のkdump.serviceが起動しない

Tags: linux, rhel

OS：RHEL 8.2
メモリ：2048 MB
プロセッサ：1

上記スペックのDNSサーバのkdump.serviceが動きません。
仮想マシンを立ち上げて、以下のコマンドで状態を確認。

`systemctl status kdump.service`

結果

```
● kdump.service - Crash recovery kernel arming
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kdump.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-06-19 18:22:29 JST; 2min 13s ago
  Process: 1014 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kdumpctl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1014 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 6月 19 18:22:28 dns.racdomain.jp systemd[1]: Starting Crash recovery kernel arming...
 6月 19 18:22:29 dns.racdomain.jp kdumpctl[1062]: kdump: kexec: failed to load kdump kernel
 6月 19 18:22:29 dns.racdomain.jp kdumpctl[1062]: kdump: Starting kdump: [FAILED]
 6月 19 18:22:29 dns.racdomain.jp systemd[1]: kdump.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 6月 19 18:22:29 dns.racdomain.jp systemd[1]: kdump.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 6月 19 18:22:29 dns.racdomain.jp systemd[1]: Failed to start Crash recovery kernel arming.
```

`systemctl restart kdump.service`

結果

```
Job for kdump.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status kdump.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`journalctl -xe`

結果

```
-- Unit kdump.service has begun starting up.
 6月 19 18:27:24 dns.racdomain.jp kdumpctl[2813]: kdump: kexec: failed to load kdump kernel
 6月 19 18:27:24 dns.racdomain.jp kdumpctl[2813]: kdump: Starting kdump: [FAILED]
 6月 19 18:27:24 dns.racdomain.jp systemd[1]: kdump.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 6月 19 18:27:24 dns.racdomain.jp systemd[1]: kdump.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- The unit kdump.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
 6月 19 18:27:24 dns.racdomain.jp systemd[1]: Failed to start Crash recovery kernel arming.
-- Subject: Unit kdump.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit kdump.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

/etc/default/grubにはまだcrachkernelパラメータを追加していません。しかしネット記事でよく見かけるようなメモリ確保が原因のエラーなのでしょうか？

ちなみにメモリを10GB積んでいる同じくRHEL 8.2でもkdump.serviceが起動してこず、そっちでは試しにcrashkernel=autoを追記してgrub2-mkconfig～コマンドを実行、再起動しましたがやはりkdump.serviceはコケてます。

原因がわかる方教えてください。

補足情報：試しにCentOS 8.2をインストールしてみました。いつも/etc/yum.confにOSとカーネルバージョンだけはアップデートしないように追記して全体のアップデートをかけるのですが、結果、kdumpがコケてました。仕方なくカーネルバージョンも含めアップデートすると起動するようになりました。多分原因はコレな気がしますが、元のOS・カーネルバージョンを保持したい場合はどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: `cat /proc/cmdline`でカーネルパラメーターに`crashkernel=auto`が渡されているかは確認されましたでしょうか？

Comment: [RedHat のマニュアル](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/installing-kdumpmanaging-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel) も参照してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。はい。/proc/cmdlineにも反映されていたのですがどうにもダメでした。/etc/yum.confの中でkernel-*とredhat-release-*しか除外しておらず、kmod-*等を弾いてなかったため、メモリの問題というより依存関係がおかしくなっていたのだと思われます。検証環境だったので、いっそのことカーネルもアップデートしてしまいました。

Answer (score 0):

/etc/yum.conf
exclude=kernel-* redhat-release*

これでアップデートをかけたのがおそらく原因でした。

kmod-* perf* python-perf* microcode_ctl-*
これらも除外対象に入れないと後で面倒くさいことになることがわかりました。

update前に戻すかupdateしてしまうか迷いましたが、RAC環境構築済だったので戻す方がリスクが高い気がしたためカーネルアップデートして解決しました。

コメントくださった方々ありがとうございます。